# CentOS VM boots into blank screen

Tags: centos, boot, virtualbox, virtual-machine

On CentOS VM, I "powered off the machine" while it was malfunctioning in login screen as it would prevent me typing the complete password. And now it fails to boot as it gets stuck in a blank screen after the boot log messages.

Almost all init boot messages have been OK, except for Network Manager, which took fairly long and I disabled it anyway through maintenance mode. But the black screen still persists. The only fail messages appearing on screen, are `failed to start security auditing service.` and/or `failed to start crash recovery kernel arming.`

I'd appreciate any help regarding how to recover the system.

Comment: Welcome on the Unix SE! Tip: maybe if you would ask for, how to debug it, it would help. The problem is with this question, that no one could really fix it, only one having access to your VM.